# Core Data - sharing NSManagedObjects among multiple threads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I suffered all the consequences of using a single MOC in multiple threads - my app crashes at random points because the MOC is created in the main thread and I also use it to fill the DB in another thread.
Though the code is synchronized (@synchronize) using a global singleton the app crashes.
I read that using a separate MOC for each thread will make things ok but I also read that it is considered also a bad approach to share NSManagedObjects across threads.

My use case is the following:
1)I load and parse XML from a server and during the parsing I insert each new NSManagedObject in the database. This all happens in a separate thread.
2)From the main thread the user interacts with the UI which reads data from the database.

In both threads I use NSManagedObjects. How would you suggest me to fix this? I failed multiple times already.

Most often the app creashed with error suggesting that I am modifying a collection while enumerating it which is not true as the code is synchronized and while I am iterating it no modifying happens and vice versa - while I modify it I don't iterate and I save once I am done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use one `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread. If you communicate between threads, pass the `NSManagedObjectID`, which is thread safe, and fetch the object again from you thread context. In my apps I sometimes even use one context per controller.

To manage the different contexts, register an Observer for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidChangeNotification`. Within this notification handling, you pass the notification to each of your contexts via the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` method. This method is thread save and makes the context update its state.

After this you have to refresh your views. If you have a table view based application, have a look at `NSFetchedResultsController`. This helps you update the table automatically with appropriate animations. If you don't use table views, you have to implement the UI update yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only supporting iOS 5 and above you don't need to deal with `NSManagedObjectID` and merging contexts anymore. You can use the new concurrency types of `NSManagedObjectContext` instead. Then do your operations within `managedObjectContext:performBlock` and they will be merged automatically.

See the answer from svena here for more information:
[Core Data and Concurrency using NSOperationQueues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770742/core-data-and-concurrency-using-nsoperationqueues)