# After executing fetch request properties of fetched object are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am fetching an array of managed objects from some entity. After executeFetchRequest returns I NSLog elements and their properties and everything is fine. After I return my newly generated array and try to use it in a background thread or some other method the properties of managed objects inside the array become nil. This is the code:

Utakmice -NSManagedObject subclass

```
    - (NSArray*)ucitajPodatke:(NSDate*)zaDatum drzavaId:(int)_drzavaId
    {

            NSManagedObjectContext *con = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [con setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];
            [con setStalenessInterval:0];
            [con setUndoManager:nil];
            // create request and predicate
            // set return result type to NSManagedObjectResultType
            ...
            ...

        return fetchedObjects; -> This works cause I can log everything and all values R OK...
    }

    -(void)SomeMethod
        NSArray *array  = [self ucitajPodatke:danas drzavaId:self.drzavaId];

        Utakmice *tekma = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i", [tekma.uniqueId intValue]); -> everything is fine


        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.35 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

                if (array != nil && [array count]>0)
                {
                    Utakmice *tekma1 = [array objectAtIndex:0];
                    DLog(@"%@", tekma1.uniqueId);
                    DLog(@"%i", [tekma1.uniqueId intValue]); -> all properties have nil value
    ...
    ...
```

Any suggestions?? I really dont know where to go from here...

One more thing. In ucitajPodatke method, when I set return result type to NSDictionaryResultType -> everything is ok... (I need managed objects cause I need relations)...
Thx in advanced

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I finally google it: 
[Core Data - sharing NSManagedObjects among multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874492/core-data-sharing-nsmanagedobjects-among-multiple-threads)

It appears that U can not pass managed objects between threads, Instead U should pass managed object id's

Comment: Yes that's correct.  Alternately create a new MOC on the thread you plan to use for executing the fetch and processing the results.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do, to keep strong reference of fetched array,
after that you can do your dispatch.

That will be good to call

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35];
```

instead of dispatching.

This issue also can be related with "Data faulting".
The data is being fetched when you access to object fields.
If you want to fully fetch objects without faulting you can use

```
NSFetchRequest *request = ...;// your fetch request here
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:YES];
// Fetch here
```

Comment: Hmmm If U look at my code, I log data after fetch and the data is ok it only becomes useless after dispatching it to another thread...

Comment: By passing the data to another thread causes this problem. Try to use performSelector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35   and have a strong property to fetched array, to access the array from someMethod

Comment: this will not open a new thread, the method will be called on main thread, and this issue should disappear.

Comment: I need data in another thread so this is not the solution, the solution is to pass data by managed id