# Pass NSManagedObjectContext between threads

Tags: core-data, thread-safety, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is it safe to initialize `NSManagedContext` in one thread and then pass it to another thread where you do inserts/fetches inside `performBlock:` ?

So https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876800/2645683 mentions `performBlock:` and relates to my question but its not sufficient. It doesnt explicity say anything about thread which created context, and thread that executes block, and fact that these will be different threads.

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12874637/2645683 seems to be outdated. Since you cant have managed context per thread and use `performBlock:` because block can execute on different thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data - sharing NSManagedObjects among multiple threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874492/core-data-sharing-nsmanagedobjects-among-multiple-threads)

Comment: @DanielCompton Nah, he has more specific problem, and the accepted answer seems to be outdated.

Comment: Initializing `NSManagedObjectContext` is relatively "lightweight" operation, why do you need to do it in different thread?

Comment: @MichałCiuba i dont need to do it in different thread. I would love to do it in the same thread :) but how can i initialize context on the same thread that runs `performBlock:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to initialize NSManagedContext in one thread and then pass it to another thread where you do inserts/fetches inside `performBlock:`?

It's safe if you do **everything that touches Core Data** inside a `performBlock:` call. Inserts and fetches, sure. But also any time you touch a managed object in any way at all, including using the property values of an object you have already fetched.

You mention that *"...you cant have managed context per thread and use performBlock:..."* That's not true-- you can have as many managed object contexts as you need, and use `performBlock:` with them.

Comment: Thanks for answer. About that context per thread: performBlock will run block (with inserts, fetches...) on thread which is different then thread that initialized context. So there will be more then one thread that uses context.